# Union of Spark DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've tried this code to add a row to a dataframe if df2 is empty but I get this error and I don't understand the reason. I don't have any column called value.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (1): value
New column names (2): country, code**

`var df1 = Seq.empty[(String,String)].toDF("country","code").`

`val df2 = spark.emptyDataFrame`

`if (df2.isEmpty) df1 = df1.union(Seq("GLOBAL" , "EMPTY").toDF("country","code"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataframes, like datasets and RDDs, are immutable. So you need to create a new Dataframe when appending a row to it.
The Dataframe `union()` method is used to combine two DataFrames of the same structure or schema. If schemas are not the same it returns an error.

To respect the schemas, you need to use the `union` method on `df1`.
To create a new DataFrame with the row you want you should use something like:

```
 val df3 = df1.union(Seq("GLOBAL" , "EMPTY").toDF())
```

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, Controls is just df1. I edited the code. I need df1 because is a DataFrame that is updated when an event occurs

Comment: Does it work now ? Try using df1.union(Seq("GLOBAL" , "EMPTY").toDF())

Comment: I should add the columns to toDF() I think

Comment: Yes indeed. Only on databricks one-column DataFrames can be left empty:
val firstDF = spark.range(3).toDF("myCol")
val newRow = Seq(20)
val appended = firstDF.union(newRow.toDF())
display(appended)